# Can't obtain the result i expect with a SQL query

Tags: sql

Hope everything is going well, so i'm stuck in a SQL query, i can obtain like 90% of the expected results, but in the last test i got an error.

**In my query on the conditions i need to access an ALIAS from SELECT and a column from the INNER JOIN**

Everything i read it says to me to use an Group by and HAVING, when i need to use a ALIAS from select

But when i want to filter using the column from the inner join it gives me an error, everything i read about that says to use a WHERE clause

This is a small example what i need but it gives me error when i use the T2.id = 123

```
SELECT
T1.user as username,
T1.amount,
T1.iduser
FROM
payments AS T1
    INNER JOIN users AS T2 ON T2.id = T1.iduser
GROUP BY username, T2.id
HAVING  
 1=1
 AND
    CASE 
        WHEN 
            username = 'xxx'
        THEN 
            T1.amount*-1 ELSE T1.amount END AND T2.id = 123
ORDER BY 
    CASE
        WHEN 
            username = 'xxx'
        THEN
            T1.amount*-1 ELSE T1.amount END desc, T1.id DESC
```

*This query is just and example what i need, probably will make no sense*

Do you guys can help me find a way to have access to the ALIAS from
a SELECT and the INNER JOIN column? I'm dying inside :D

Comment: the query is to big, to help you as also e don't have data, an approach is to remove all till you got 1 tqable and their columns and then ass the rest one table at the time and check if the result is still what you expect,  and the group by and finally the HAVINg clause

Answer (score 0):

I think it is failing because the T2.id is not in the GROUP BY clause:

Would this solve your issue (moving only `T2.id IN ('something')` to the WHERE clause)?:

```
FROM
payments AS T1
    INNER JOIN users AS T2 ON T2.id = T1.iduser
    LEFT JOIN users_management AS T3 ON T3.id = T1.created_by
    LEFT JOIN common.countries AS T4 ON T4.iso3 = T1.idcountry
    LEFT JOIN payment_types AS T5 ON T5.id = T1.provider

--This is the change, removed from having, placed in where
WHERE T2.id IN ('something')

GROUP BY amount, T1.transaction_type, T1.id, T1.iduser
HAVING  1=1
  AND
    CASE amount WHEN T1.transaction_type = 1 AND
              funds_status = "FUNDS_REMOVED" AND
              (
                          type = "credit_note" OR
                          type = "chargeback" OR
                          type = "refund"
                  )
             THEN T1.amount*-1 ELSE T1.amount END BETWEEN -1000 AND 10000
ORDER BY CASE
         WHEN T1.transaction_type = 1 AND
              funds_status = "FUNDS_REMOVED" AND
              (
                          type = "credit_note" OR
                          type = "chargeback" OR
                          type = "refund"
                  )
             THEN
                 T1.amount*-1 ELSE T1.amount END desc, T1.id DESC
```

Apologies in advance, I can't test with the current information, but this is my best guess

Comment: In a where statement it works but then the condition doesn't work because it uses the alias funds_stats, and i already tried to put the T2.id on the group by and it didn't work, getting out of ideas :p Thank you